# CSS slanted menu

Tags: css

While searching for Jquery/CSS menus I came across this site:

http://www.freshdesignweb.com/css-drop-down-navigation-menu.html

If you look at the first picture there is a menu that is slanted, like it's hanging off a hinge, that looks pretty darn awesome, so I clicked that link and went to the site but nowhere did I find that slanted menu, not on the site, not in  the demo :(

While I think it's pretty irritating someone would photoshop that, I was wondering if "Is it actually possible to make that kind of slanted menu using CSS?"

Comment: Yes...using `transform:rotate` See [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/55tqejud/)

Comment: Thanks guys! Will vote both up and pick the answer that came first. @Paulie_D Why you think it would be bad UX?

Comment: Unless you're trying to start a trend it's going to confuse people AND it's a nightmare to manage in terms of browser window sizes. The web is basically up/down & left/right - adding rotation is all very well but it just looks 'odd'.

Comment: Heh! The oddness is what got my attention :) While I do agree if a lot of elements on the page started looking weird it would be weird but I thought just one menu (eg: settings) would be eye catching enough. But the browser window sizes is a valid point that I didnt think of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly possible although I think it would be poor UX

EDIT - You can even have submenus rotated back - [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/55tqejud/1/)

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    margin: 25px 0 0  25px;
    padding: 0;
    width:250px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    list-style:none;
        
    transform:rotate(-35deg);
    transform-origin:top  right;
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding:0.25em
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Filve</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Very very cool! Gonna play with this now :)  
But why do you think it will be bad UX?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to use CSS `transform`. Check out the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cw19own/) I created.

HTML

```
<div class="slanted">
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slanted {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```